# Elegant algorithm to pivot a dictionary using arbitrary keys

Tags: python, data-structures

I'm looking for an elegant way to convert d1 to d2. I would prefer to avoid a rat's nest of for loops if possible. Ideally, the solution would be readable and reusable. I'm writing in python, but a solution in any language that doesn't use language-specific features would be very helpful.

```
d1 = {
    "A": {
        "Category1": 11111,
        "Category2": 22222,
        "Category3": 33333
    },
    "B": {
        "Category1": 44444,
        "Category2": 55555,
        "Category3": 66666
    },
}

d2 = {
    "Category1": {
        "A": 111111,
        "B": 444444
    },
    "Category2": {
        "A": 222222,
        "B": 555555
    },
    "Category3": {
        "A": 333333,
        "B": 666666
    }
}
```

To be clear - I'm not looking for a solution to this specific input. The code is pretty trivial (see below). The problem with this code is that it is brittle and cannot be used to solve other related problems

```
def pivot(d):
    data = {}
    for key, val in d.items():
        for key2, val2 in val.items():
            if key2 not in data:
                data[key2] = {}

            data[key2][key] = val2
    return data
```

A more complicate example:

```
d1 = {
    "A": {
        "Category1": {
            "X": 111111,
            "Y": 222222,
        },
        "Category2": {
            "X": 333333,
            "Y": 444444,
        },
        "Category3": {
            "X": 555555,
            "Y": 666666,
        }
    },
    "B": {
        "Category1": {
            "X": 777777,
            "Y": 888888,
        },
        "Category2": {
            "X": 999999,
            "Y": 101010,
        },
        "Category3": {
            "X": 101011,
            "Y": 101012,
        }
    },
}

d2 = {
    "X": {
        "Category1": {
            "A": 111111,
            "B": 777777,
        },
        "Category2": {
            "A": 333333,
            "B": 999999,
        },
        "Category3": {
            "A": 555555,
            "B": 101011,
        },
    },
    "Y": {
        "Category1": {
            "A": 222222,
            "B": 888888,
        },
        "Category2": {
            "A": 444444,
            "B": 101010,
        },
        "Category3": {
            "A": 666666,
            "B": 101012,
        },
    },
}
```

Comment: Consider for a moment how you would do this by hand. Write down the steps you would take. Then write those steps in code. There will be a few loops. Or perhaps there is some Python syntax that will hide the loops from you.

Comment: Thanks for the response Jim. I have updated the question. The code to solve this specific problem is trivial. My question is whether it is possible to write it in a more generic way.

Comment: In what way more generic? Can you show an example where this code would not work? Do you want to abstract away the names `"children"` and `"count"`? Or do you want to make this work for an arbitrary number of nesting levels?

Comment: I have clarified the question and adjusted the title. I would like to pivot a dictionary by an arbitrary set of keys. It should be generic so that it can handle an arbitrarily deep data structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I found something reasonable. Here is a sketch of the code without all the edge case checks:

```
def flatten_dict(d):
    if type(d) != dict:
        return [[d]]

    arr = []
    for k, v in d.items():
        for el in flatten_dict(v):
            arr.append([k] + el)

    return arr

def rearrange(in_arrs, order):
    out_arrs = []
    for arr in in_arrs:
        out_arrs += [[arr[idx] for idx in order] + [arr[-1]]]

    return out_arrs

def nest(arrays, root=None):
    if len(arrays) == 0:
        return {}


    d = root or defaultdict(dict)
    for arr in arrays:
        if len(arr) >= 2:
            head, *tail = arr
            if len(tail) == 1:
                d[head] = tail[0]
            elif len(tail) > 1:
                d[head] = nest([tail], d[head])
    return d

def pivot(d, order):
    flattened = flatten_dict(d)
    rearranged = rearrange(flattened, order)
    nested = nest(rearranged)

    return nested

d1 = {
    "A": {
        "Category1": {
            "X": 111111,
            "Y": 222222,
        },
        "Category2": {
            "X": 333333,
            "Y": 444444,
        },
        "Category3": {
            "X": 555555,
            "Y": 666666,
        }
    },
    "B": {
        "Category1": {
            "X": 777777,
            "Y": 888888,
        },
        "Category2": {
            "X": 999999,
            "Y": 101010,
        },
        "Category3": {
            "X": 101011,
            "Y": 101012,
        }
    },
}

print(pivot(d, [2, 1,0])

{
    "X": {
        "Category1": {
            "A": 111111,
            "B": 777777,
        },
        "Category2": {
            "A": 333333,
            "B": 999999,
        },
        "Category3": {
            "A": 555555,
            "B": 101011,
        },
    },
    "Y": {
        "Category1": {
            "A": 222222,
            "B": 888888,
        },
        "Category2": {
            "A": 444444,
            "B": 101010,
        },
        "Category3": {
            "A": 666666,
            "B": 101012,
        },
    },
}
```

**Update:** In case it's of interest to anyone, I wrapped this code up with a number of other utilities into this project https://github.com/adieyal/dictutils